# Azure function Application settings is not consistent to values in local.settings.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions

`local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": 1,
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT": true
  }
}
```

However, after successfully executing:

```
$ npm run-script build && zip -r azure_function.zip .  && az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g acmeapp -n acmefunction2 --src azure_function.zip 

...


Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
  "end_time": "2023-08-08T16:22:50.8690074Z",
  "id": "3cba98a7-a231-45b8-847a-f0222e38731c",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2023-08-08T16:22:50.8690074Z",
  "log_url": "https://acmefunction2.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "received_time": "2023-08-08T16:21:36.1656327Z",
  "site_name": "acmefunction2",
  "start_time": "2023-08-08T16:21:38.0518534Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://acmefunction2.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}
```

The function is deployed to Azure function app.

But in `Settings | Configuration | Application settings`:

[image]

As you can see:
`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` is set to "node", which is as expected.

`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` is set to 0, why not 1?

`SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` is set to `false`, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Functions, `local.settings.json` file is meant for local development and isn't directly used when you deploy the function to Azure. Instead, the settings in `local.settings.json` need to be manually applied to the Application Settings in the Azure portal or through command-line tools like the Azure CLI. This separation ensures that developers can have local settings that don't necessarily override the production settings.

To ensure your settings in `local.settings.json` are reflected in the Azure Function App, you can use the Azure CLI to set them:

```bash
az functionapp config appsettings set --name acmefunction2 --resource-group acmeapp --settings FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=node WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=linux%2Cportal%2Cv2%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-typescript#project-file-deployment

Use the `-publish-local-settings` option to automatically create app settings in your function app based on values in the local.settings.json file.